# Dynamic String[] for twitter typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I am doing an ajax call to return a list of objects. Once the object array is populated, a separate string[] is populated with the Objects' names. I would like to pass this to twitter typeahead using a Bloodhound source.

-So far I can see the bloodhound gets populated with all the strings but the twitter hint isn't working properly.

Bloodhound -

```
var clientList = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: [Clients.entitiesNames]});
clientList.initialize();
```

Typeahead - initialized after

```
$('#search-box).typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            source: clientList
        }
    );
```

Like I said, I know that the bloodhound gets populated with the correct number of indices in the array but the twitter hint doesn't appear. I'm using bootstrap 3. I also have the ajax to render the Object[] in a init() that's called on page load in js. Once the ajax finishes, the init() for the twitter typeahead is called.

I thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that BOTH the bloodhound and typeahead are called after the string array has been initialized and it will work.